# Text editor selection settings to include "$" and "-"?

Tags: jquery, sublimetext2, sublimetext, text-editor, atom-editor

It bugs me, especially when dealing with jQuery, that when I use `cmd+d` (in Sublime Text or Atom) or double click on a variable, it highlights everything except dollar signs and hyphens.

For example, double clicking on "$hello" will only highlight "hello". Are there any editor settings so that I can select the entire variable including these special characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The setting you are looking for in Sublime is `"word_separators"`. Its default value is

```
"word_separators": "./\\()\"'-:,.;<>~!@#$%^&*|+=[]{}`~?",
```

Copy and paste this into your user settings, and remove any characters you don't want, such as `$` or `-`. If you only want this to apply to a certain syntax, such as JavaScript, open a JS file, select **`Preferences -> Settings-More -> Syntax Specific-User`**, add the setting there, and save the settings file.

Comment: Much much love for u!